# + operator on binary types

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators, byte

When 'adding' binary types, is it more common to add together their values or concat together the bytes? For example:

```
=0x12 + 0xA
```

Is it more common for this to equal:

```
0x120A
```

Or:

```
0x1C
```

I mean mostly in a SQL context, as I'm sure when used in a programming language it converts the bytes to number before the operator is applied. Is this defined in the SQL standard, or its open to vendor implementation?

Here's a reference from SQL Server: [String Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: One does not ordinarily apply any operators to binary values in my experience. Probably because binary values are usually things that represent objects - image, encoded file, enrypted  scalar value, structure from an application stored, etc. If you are asking why the plus operator treats your values as string and applies concatenation, well that's documented. Using math directly on binary values is not supported; try any other mathematical operator to see the "incompatible" error message.

Comment: @SMor agreed for atomic/non-packed values (image, hash, etc.) but If storing packed values I think it could be useful -- `&`, `|`, and I suppose `+` and `-` and `~`. For example, "what users have this email preference (bit) applied?" Updating a setting across all users, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you see `+` and think "addition".  That's just silly!  (That is a joke.)

SQL Server overloads `+` so it is both addition and string concatenation.  With binary constants, "string" concatenation is used.  This is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  For `+` as addition:

> Is any valid expression of any one of the data types in the numeric category except the bit data type.

And then on the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for `+` as string concatenation:

> Is any valid expression of any one of the data types in the character and binary data type category, except the image, ntext, or text data types.

So, SQL Server decides that you really want string concatenation.

If you really want to add them, convert them to numbers and back to binary:

```
select cast(cast(0x12 as int) + cast(0xA as int) as binary(1))
```

Comment: is the SQL Server implementation common among the other main vendors, or its done differently for each?

Comment: @David542 . . . There is absolutely no standard concerning this issue.  Only SQL Server (well and Sybase) overload `+` as string concatenation and `binary` is handled uniquely in each database, if it is even supported.